A blessing on an incomplete Mishnah bread on Shabbat
Is it permissible to make a blessing on Shabbat on an incomplete loaf of bread? And in the event that it looks outwardly complete but is actually incomplete, is it allowed? For example, the Challah looks like a rectangular cake and every time you slice it, its shape still looks like a rectangle, only the length is shortened? Is it better to take a slice instead of Challah that looks whole?

Full halachic discussion: https://dinonline.org/2014/01/20/lechem-mishneh-the-double-bread-of-shabbos/
